# Limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n\ (\mathrm{mod}\ r)}{r}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

By accident I came across the following,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n\ (\mathrm{mod}\ r)}{r}=0.4227\ldots\approx 1-\gamma,$$

where the numerator is the remainder of $n$ divided by $r$. Is it known whether we have equality in the above expression or is it just a numerical coincidence? Has this been studied?

Edit: I'm sorry for all the (important) typos, everything should be fixed now.

Comment: Without conditions on n, I have a hard time believing that lim inf of the sum is as large as you claim.  I do not think the limit exists.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.17

Comment: The text is incorrect (should be the remainder of $n$ divided by $r$)

Comment: Can the OP prove this, or is this an experimental fact?

Comment: Further, I see no way of rescuing the problem without making the denominator substantially bigger, as in r^2 or n^2, or making the numerator correspondingly smaller. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.17

Comment: @Igor: thanks for spotting the typo. And no, I cannot prove this, this is purely experimental.

Comment: The $r=2$ term is $\frac12$ for every odd $n$, so how can can the limit be less than $\frac12$?

Comment: @Brandon, look at the $\frac{1}{n}$-term in front

Comment: Woett, there likely was no 1/n in front when Brendan McKay made his comment.  There certainly wasn't when I made my earlier comments.  Gerhard "However, All Is Better Now" Paseman, 2012.04.17

Comment: Then I said nothing :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This follows by elementary computation: we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n\bmod r}r&=\sum_{r\le n}\frac nr-\sum_{r\le n}\left\lfloor\frac nr\right\rfloor\\\\
&=nH_n-|\{(r,s)\in\mathbb N^2:1\le rs\le n\}|\\\\
&=nH_n-2\sum_{r\le\sqrt n}\left\lfloor\frac nr\right\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2\\\\
&=nH_n-2nH_{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}+n+O(\sqrt n),
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n\bmod r}r&=H_n-2H_{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}+1+O(n^{-1/2})\\
&=\log n+\gamma-2\log\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor-2\gamma+1+O(n^{-1/2})\\\\
&=1-\gamma+O(n^{-1/2}).
\end{align}

Comment: Fir clarity, I would change the indexing rs <= n to  set notation that said something like the set of pairs of positive integers (r,s) with r,s <= n.  For me that would remove the ambiguity of whether r or s or both are the index, as well as whether negative r and negative s were allowed.  Gerhard "Nice Derivation, By The Way" Paseman, 2012.04.17

Comment: You are right, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: To add to Emil's nice answer: The determination of the OP's limit is implicit in Dirichlet's estimate for the average order of the divisor function, namely $\sum_{k=1}^{n} d(k) = n \log{n} + (2\gamma-1)n + O(\sqrt{n})$. (See section 18.2 in Hardy and Wright, for example.) To see the connection, notice that the sum in question is exactly the number of ordered pairs of natural numbers $(r,s)$ with $rs \leq n$ (and now compare with Emil's answer above). 

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, I guess I should have mentioned in the answer that this estimate of $\sum_{r\le n}\lfloor n/r\rfloor$ is a classical fact.